# Count row with data and specific value from excel in VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have 2  Labels (**lblTotal**) and (**lblYes**) which I put on my form. I want to read an excel file and count how many people come and how many say "yes", like this ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai44p.jpg)). So "lblTotal" will count all row with data (exclude table header) and "lblYes" will show the counting of Answer with "Yes" which updates in **real time**. So far I got the **lblTotal** to work:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
Dim xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing

Public Sub Total()
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open("D:\Question\Data.xlsx")
        xlApp.Visible = False
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim xx As Integer = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        lblTotal.Text = xx.ToString()
        xlApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

However, I have no idea how to count row that has the **Yes** answer. Also this doesn't allow real time update. Even though I use a timer to do the job (update on each tick) but it takes it too much to load. For example, in the code above, I used Button to refresh by calling the Total() function in the button click event.

I was thinking about the Button Save event that triggered this update as well. But my biggest question is how can I make it count "Yes" answer only?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) will help.

Comment: Thank. That give me a way of new search but what should I start?
    xlworksheet.range("D1").autofilter

Comment: Looks like Gabriels' approach of simply running through the range and counting the "Yes" values works for you. It's probably a better solution than applying a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, inside the Total() function:

```
    Dim WorkSheetPath As String = "D:\Question\Data.xlsx"
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Range As Excel.Range
    Dim rCnt As Integer
    Dim Obj As Object

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkSheetPath)
    xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    Range = xlWorksheet.UsedRange
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For rCnt = 1 To Range.Rows.Count
        Obj = CType(Range.Cells(rCnt, 4), Excel.Range) 'if you change the index of the answer column in your excel file, change the index here as well (it is 4 right now)
        Dim answer As String = Obj.Value.ToString()
        If answer = "Yes" Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
    xlWorkbook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    lblTotal.Text = count.ToString()
```

Hope this helps. ^^

Comment: Dim workbook As New ExcelDocument

error woth not defined.

Comment: Can you please explain it? I am not sure I understood your error

Comment: ExcelDocument is not defined.

Comment: Have you imported the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference where you have this piece of code?

Comment: isn't it suppose to be Excel.Application? I think

Comment: Will try to change it to Excel.Application, will be back with an update in a few minutes

Comment: Hello again,
It works well with the sample but when I move the column to index 9
No, Name, Sex, Dob,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3,Code,Answer.

I got error System.NullReferenceException

it errors at Dim answer as String = Obj.Value.ToString()

Comment: Have you checked the names? (maybe the sheet name changed, or the workbook etc) or you have an empty cell or you forgot to replace 4 in my code sample with 9?

Comment: Firs, sorry StackOverflow, my reputation is too low to go to chat.

@Gabrel, Yes I have checked everything. If I change index 6 or 7 or 8 ... it works just show not correct result. But 9 will throw error.

Comment: Can you provide another image of your new excel sheet?

Comment: Try creating a new Excel worksheet, add the data from the photo in it, then delete the first worksheet. Update the code sample if there have been any name changes (the name of the .xlsx file, or the sheet name etc)

Comment: Ok, I found the reason. It seem that if the excel file edit manually using MS.Excel it will worked. But if using VB.net to add new data ... will result error.

Comment: Will be looking for this issue a little later. Also, would you like to accept my edit on your post? It would be easier for further viewers to follow the topic. Thank you!